# How to track all new YouTube uploads by tags/description?

Tags: youtube

Is there way to track all new uploaded videos by specific tag or description?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a Google Alert thing for new search results that contain `your phrase` and `site:youtube.com/watch` would do the trick. It however is not possible on YouTube itself.